# Integral differentiation with infinite bound (differentiation of expected value)

Tags: integration, derivatives

I am trying to proove the following:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_x^{\infty}(z-x)f_Z(z)dz=1-F_Z(x)$$

Where $f_Z$ and $F_Z$ are resp. the probability density and cumulative distribution functions of a random variable $Z > 0$, i.e.:

$$F_Z(x) = \int_0^xf_Z(t)$$

My final goal is to proove the following:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\mathbb{E}\left[max\{Z-x, 0\}\right]=1-F_Z(x)$$

*What I have tried:* Use the definition of $\mathbb{E}[X]$ and apply Leibniz integral rule (I am stuck with the infinite upper bound and I did not found anything that could explain what to do with it):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_x^{\infty}(z-x)f_Z(z)dz=\int_x^{\infty}-f_Z(z)dz + A(x) - 0$$

I have $A(x)=h(x,\infty).b'(x)$ where $h(x,z) = (z - x)f_Z(z)$ and $b(x) = \infty$, so I am assuming $b'(x)=0$, but within this assumption I have a minus sign that should not be there.

There must be a mistake somewhere in my reasoning but since I cannot find it by myself I came here looking for any hints!

Comment: what exactly are h and b????

Comment: And how are $\int_{0}^{x}f_{Z}(z)dz$ and $\int_{x}^{\infty}f_{Z}(z)dz$ related? What if you add them?

Comment: @TrialAndError I know their sum is $1$, but at the end I still $F_Z(x) - 1$, the minus sign is still there, or maybe I misunderstood the intention of your comment?

Comment: @user254665 Sorry, this is simply the Leibniz formula, $b(x)$ is the upper bound of the integral, $b(x)=\infty$ here, which is what cause me trouble... $h(x,z)$ is the function inside the integral: $h(x,z)=(z-x)f_Z(z)$. I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see it either ...
\begin{align}
    \frac{d}{dx}\int_x^{\infty}(z-x)f_Z(z)dz & = \frac{d}{dx}\int_{x}^{\infty}zf_Z(z)dz-\frac{d}{dx}x\int_{x}^{\infty}f_Z(z)dz \\
 & = -xf_{Z}(x)-\int_{x}^{\infty}f_Z(z)dz-x\frac{d}{dx}\int_{x}^{\infty}f_Z(z)dz \\
  & = -xf_Z(x)-\int_{x}^{\infty}f_Z(z)dz+xf_Z(x) \\
  & = -\int_x^{\infty}f_Z(z)dz = 1-\int_x^{\infty}f_Z(z)dz-1 \\
  & = F_Z(x)-1.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Use Fubini (Tonelli):
$$
\begin{align}
 \frac{d}{dx}\int_x^{\infty}(z-x)f_Z(z)dz & = \frac{d}{dx}\int_{x}^{\infty}f_Z(z) \int_{x}^z dy\,dz \\
 & = \frac{d}{dx}\int_{x}^{\infty} \int_{y}^\infty f_Z(z) dz\,dy  \\
  & = - \int_{x}^\infty f_Z(z) dz = F_Z(x)-1.
\end{align}
$$